# Create an observable that summarizes every property in a dynamically created knockout view model

Tags: knockout.js

I am working on an editor that creates dynamic view models based on a template defined by the user in the admin interface of our application.  By dynamic I mean that if there are 100 data points available the user can select to only include 50 data points and their associated prompts in their template.  The prompt is displayed in the UI like "Patient Age: ".  I pull this template down to the client and generate a knockout view model with only the selected properties.  The end goal of the editor is to collect all required values and then display them in a summary window.  When I originally started thinking through this I figured I would create a computedObservable to hold the summary and then (waves hand) all the properties from the dynamic model could be summarized within that observable.  I'm good up until the point where I try to summarize all the property values and the prompts in a single string that is updated in real time in a preview window.  Has anyone done anything like this?

I know I could take the straightforward path of just including every possible property in the computedObservable and test for the existence of the property before trying to pull in the value, but I have to believe there is a better approach I am not thinking of.

I've included no code because I'm looking more for guidance on approach than on a working example.

EDIT: adding a simplified example to narrow down the scope of what I'm asking.  I realize that the answers given so far are off-base due to my inability to clearly ask what I'm looking for.

My application will dynamically create a knockout view model based on the content of a json object I download from the server.  Because I don't know what this object will look like at design time, I can't create the "Summary" observable in my javascript code, it has to be created dynamically as well.

Here's a simplified example:

Assuming I have a knockout view model mapped using ko.mapping from this JSON object (cut down for brevity):

```
{  
   "InitialGraphical":{  
      "GraphicalNoteId":0,
      "GraphicalNoteTemplateId":0,
      "NoteType":0,
      "InitialGraphical":{  
         "InitialGraphicalId":0,
         "InitialGraphicalEligibilityVerificationId":0,
         "ContinueReviewPer":null,
         "BirthSummary":null,
         "MaternalAge":null,
         "Gravida":null,
         "Para":null,
         "BirthWeight":null,
         "GestationalAge":null,
         "Delivery":null,
         "Apgar1Minute":null,
         "Apgar5Minute":null,
         "Apgar10Minute":null,
         "IPPlanOfCareSummary":null
      },
      "DailyDetails":{  
         "DailyDetailsId":0,
         "DateStart":"/Date(-62135578800000)/",
         "DateEnd":"/Date(-62135578800000)/",
         "Grams":0,
         "BedTypeId":0,
         "AdditionalBedTypeInfo":null,
         "VPShuntResivoirPatent":false,
         "Functional":false,
         "NASScore":0,
         "ScoreRange":null,
         "ScoreDate":"/Date(-62135578800000)/",
         "SeizureActivity":null,
         "HeadCircumference":0,
         "Rewarming":false
      }
   }
}
```

I want to dynamically create a computed observable that includes EVERY property in the view model and updates in real time.  This property I want to create is bound to a text area that will show the summary of all values entered into the view model.  So, in psuedo-code, I want to do this:

```
var Summary = ko.computed(function(){
    // iterate through all properties ViewModel and concatenate their values into 
    // a single string, then return that as the value of this computed
    // that updates when each property does.  <--- THIS IS THE QUESTION, HERE
});
```

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I can appreciate the sentiment of not including code. But this is so involved, that I think it's hard to really guide without something to work off. Otherwise, I think you might need to summarize this a little better.

Comment: @pim The best summary I can think of is:  How can I create a knockout computedObservable that includes every property in the knockout view model if I don't know the properties at design time.

Comment: @RoyJ Thanks for that, I'm already ok with iterating over object properties, this is more of a knockout question I guess.

Comment: @Mike I just saw your edit to the question. Do you want the object representing the VM, or just the values concatenated as summary? See the third snippet in my answer. It does show how to get the object representation as a computed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ko.toJSON`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) to get JSON string of the computed and observables in the ViewModel (or `ko.toJS` to get object with values).

```js
var Model = function(){
  var self= this;
  self.test = ko.observable('test');
  
  self.test2 = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.test() + "2";
  });
};

var vm = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(ko.toJSON(vm));
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: test"/> 
  <span data-bind="text: test"></span>
</div>
Test2: 
<span data-bind="text: test2"></span>
```

However trying to add a computed in the VM that returns the `ko.toJSON` means that next time `ko.toJSON(self)` is calculated the `self.summary` will also be considered in it. So, over time, the summary variable keeps getting inflated due to that. Here's an example of how that might (not) work:

```js
var Model = function(){
  var self= this;
  self.test = ko.observable('test');
  
  self.test2 = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.test() + "2";
  });
  
  self.summary = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.toJSON(self);
  });
};

var vm = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(vm.summary());
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: test"/> 
  <span data-bind="text: test"></span>
</div>
Test2: 
<span data-bind="text: test2"></span>
```

If you **must** have the summary as a computed, you could use `ko.toJS` and delete `summary` property before returning the object.

```js
var Model = function(){
  var self= this;
  self.test = ko.observable('test');
  
  self.test2 = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.test() + "2";
  });
  
  self.summary = ko.computed(function() {
    var obj = ko.toJS(self);
    delete obj.summary;
    return obj;
  });
};

var vm = new Model();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function() {
  console.log(vm.summary());
},1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: test"/> 
  <span data-bind="text: test"></span>
</div>
Test2: 
<span data-bind="text: test2"></span>
```